# Entity framework 6 or Microsoft enterprise library for mvc project

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework-6, enterprise-library

I'm looking for better architecture for my project which huge data (many stored procedures,views, tables).

Could anyone suggest which one is better - EF6 or Enterprise library to interact with data for better performance.

I know both are completely different thing. One is Object Relational Mapper and other is wrapper around ADO.NET. But i just want to know whether there will be any performance improvement if i just use enterprise library to access data in my project or should I go with the entity framework 6?

There are many stored procedures in my project.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Definitely you should use Entity Framework 6 as Enterprise library is a little bit too old. You can achieve the same performance as pure ADO.NET using it but in most cases Entity Framework allows you to create code much faster (and that really matter).